# How to reuse a model crated for crate too many model in Django?

Tags: django

I have model in `models.py` in my app Django :

```
class Personnel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    card_number = models.BigIntegerField()
    name = models.TextField(db_collation='C')  
    family = models.TextField(db_collation='C') 
    height = models.TextField(db_collation='C', blank=True, null=True) 
    weight = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    job_type = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='Job_Type', blank=True, null=True)  
    age = models.FloatField(db_column='age', blank=True, null=True)  
    Superviser_score = models.FloatField(db_column='Superviser_score', blank=True, null=True)
    QC_score = models.FloatField(db_column='QC_score', blank=True, null=True)    
    def __str__(self)-> str:
        return f'{self.card_number}  -  {self.family}  - {self.name}'
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'personnel'
```

And in `admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(Personnel)
class MyPersonelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['card_number','name','family','center','job_type']
```

---

How can I reuse `personenel` model for create too many model ?

I try below code in `models.py` for crate another model but I get error:

```
class SuperviserModel(Personnel):
    id=Personnel.id
    card_number = Personnel.card_number
    name = Personnel.name
    family = Personnel.family
    center = Personnel.center
    distance = Personnel.distance
    job_type = Personnel.job_type
    overtime = Personnel.overtime

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'personnel'
```

> Error:
> **column personnel.personnel_ptr_id does not exist LINE 1: ...d" FROM "personnel" INNER JOIN "personnel" T2 ON ("personnel... ^ )**

Note:

1. `SuperviserModel` just update 7 field from `personennl` model.
2. `QcModel` just update 2 field from `personennl` model.
3. `BioModel` just update 4 field from `personennl` model.
4. ...

Comment: > for create too many model ? I don't follow? What is `SuperviserModel` supposed to do?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I update my question. `SuperviserModel` just update 7 field from `personennl` model. And the another model I want create, update two fields of `personennl` model.

Comment: Where is that error message generated? I do not see any reference to `personnel_ptr_id` in the above class definitions.

Comment: @OldBoy `column personnel.personnel_ptr_id does not exist LINE 1: ...d" FROM "personnel" INNER JOIN "personnel" T2 ON ("personnel... ^ )`  I dont use `personnel_ptr_id` .

Comment: It looks like you are trying to join items from two different places with non-matching columns.

Comment: i am not sure, but have a strong belief that  model polymorphism can save you. there are a few libraries to provide such functionality.

Comment: @OldBoy: that is because inheritance is used: for model inheritance if both models are concrete, it places a `OneToOneField` to the parent in the child model.

Comment: But I still don't really understand the use case here. Why not user `Personnel` here, since it refers to exactly the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Don't overwrite the attributes of the parent class. The supervised model is just:

```py
class SupervisedModel(Personnel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,)
    def __str__(self)-> str:
        return f'{self.card_number}  -  {self.title} {self.family} - {self.name}'
```

Then to create a new supervised model with `title` being a new attribute:

```py
>>> hipdb.SupervisedModel.objects.create(card_number=1234567890, name='Henry', family='Johnson', title='Mr')
<SupervisedModel: 1234567890  -  Mr Johnson - Henry>
```

However, I think this approach is not very djangonic and I would recommend thinking about linking `SupervisedModel` to `Personnel` via a `OneToOneField` ([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)).

Comment: This `OneToOneField` is already done, that is what happens if you inherit from a non-abstract model: it automatically adds a hidden `OneToOneField` to the parent, that `OneToOneField` is even the primary key.